# Postgresql hot standby single table replication

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, replication

Currently we are building replication of the primary db with hotstand by referring the link

https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-postgres-hot-standby

Is there a way to replicate only a single table from the primary database?

Answer (score 0):

Only with [logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/logical-replication.html) but I don't know if this is possible on GCP.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud SQL Postgresql currently doesn’t support logical replication. There is a feature request that is publicly viewable [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/67684848) which you can up-vote with the +1 and star to get any updates.